# Kivy: Widgets are adding up

Tags: android, python, kivy

So earlier today I asked about a widget error to which inclement responded to.
His answer worked, but not perfectly. My original problem was adding a widget from a function after a button click, but every time I click the button it adds one more of itself. So first click it says "hi", second click it says "hi hi" and so on.
Here is my code(example script):

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
textshow = BoxLayout()
def answer(answer):
      text = Label(text=str(answer))
      textshow.add_widget(text)
Builder.load_string('''
<main>:
    Button: 
        on_release: root.show()
''')
class main(BoxLayout):
      def show(self):
           answer("test")
           App.get_running_app().popup.open()


class apprun(App):
     def build(self):
         self.popup = Popup(content=textshow)
         return main()
apprun().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `answer` function adds a widget to `textshow`, but you never remove any widgets so you just get more and more.

You'd be better off putting this all in a specific class rather than in these global scope variables. For instance, you could make your own popup class displaying some text however you like, and simply set this text with a StringProperty. Then you could either store one or just make a new instance each time with the text property you want.